# KeyError: 'allocated_bytes.all.current'

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface

Si I upload in huggingface spaces the VQGAN+CLIP code, the problem it that when I try to use it, it gives me this error.
[image]

I don't know what this means

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be caused by an uninitialized CUDA. Try running `torch.cuda.init()` before you execute your code. I found a similar problem in this discussion: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49952